# Rendering CALayers with CoreAnimations

Tags: ios, avassetexportsession, avcomposition, avvideocomposition

How is it possible to render CALayer that has lots of animations to a mov file?

I know how to render it with `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer` but therefore i need a dummy video (i have one 1x1px) but i am wondering how this can be done without having a mp3/mov, so simply rendering a CALayer to a video without any other resources.

Any ideas? Maybe even code examples?

Answer (score 0):

This [RenderCoreAnimationToVideo](https://github.com/JanX2/RenderCoreAnimationToVideo) will help you. Check it.

The above example is for Mac OS, but it easy to convert for iOS.

Comment: This example uses also a "blankMovieAsset"... seems not to be possible.. thanks anyways